# Multiline conditional test in PHP result seems horribly wrong

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
<?php
$a = (
  true and false
) or true;
echo("Le resultat est : " . $a . "\n");

$a = true 
  or (
  true and false
);
echo("Le resultat est : " . $a . "\n");
```

The result is **false** then **true**. By the holy hand of Helm, why?

I know that boolean operators do short-circuit. But it should be limited inside the parenthesis, not the whole expression!

Answer (score 1):

What happens in your first example is that the assignment operator has precedence over *and* and *or*.

```
$a = ( true and false ) or true;
```

So it is the same as:

```
( $a = ( true and false ) ) or true;
```

What happens here is that *$a* gets assigned *false* from the expression *true and false*, and then *$a or true* gets evaluated, but the result of that gets dumped into the void.

So what you want to do is to put parentheses around the whole expression and assign that to $a:

```
$a = (( true and false ) or true);   // Prints: 1 (for true)
```

But there is almost never a reason to use *and* and *or*. Always use *&&* and *||*, and then you'll never encounter that problem:

```
$a = ( true && false ) || true;   // Prints: 1 (for true)
```

As you can see here https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php, *and, xor,* and *or* have the lowest precedence of all operators.